What is $\int_0^T \sum_{i=\lceil x-t\rceil}^{\lfloor x+t\rfloor}f(i)\,dt$?
Let
$$
g(x,t)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\delta(y-i)f(i)  \,dy=\sum_{i=\lceil x-t\rceil}^{\lfloor x+t\rfloor}f(i)
$$
Can we make sense of
$$
\int_0^T \sum_{i=\lceil x-t\rceil}^{\lfloor x+t\rfloor}f(i)\,dt?
$$
